# Selenium InvalidSelectorException caused by single quote (python)

Tags: html, python-3.x, quotes

I have trouble selecting an element using selenium webdriver.
I am trying to get the "Student's Book" and then click the start button that belongs to it. There are several books with similar title and it's important to get exactly this book in particular. using id's to find the element does not work, because they are being generated and do not always look the same.

the html looks as follows:

```html
<table style="margin: 0; width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="/image/db/prod/pic.jpg" alt=""></td>
            <td style="padding: 0; vertical-align: top; position: relative;">
                <h3 class="top0" style="width: 200px;" id="crp_title_254">Student's Book</h3>
                <hr><a class="linkButton orangeLinkButton bold" href="some_link">Start</a>
                <a class="btn_crpdel" id="btn_crpdel_254"><img class="style-del" src="/styles/pic/style-del.png" alt="-" style="width: 23px; height: 23px;"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the python part looks like this with the material variable holding the value "Student's Book":

```
try:
    #material = "Student's Book"
    start_link = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[text()='" + material + "']/following::a[contains(text(), launch_button[self.INTERFACE_LANGUAGE])]")
    start_link.click()
except Exception as e:
    Exceptionhandling...
```

when running the above code the following exception occurs:

```
InvalidSelectorException('Given xpath expression "//h3[text()=\'Student Book\'s\']/following::a[contains(text(), launch_button[self.INTERFACE_LANGUAGE])]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.', None, None)
```

The whole thing works perfectly fine if there is no single quote in it.
Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to put the text inside double quotes? `//h3[text()="\'Student Book\'s\'"]`

Comment: @DanielCorzo Thanks for your answer. unfortunately this did not work.